# Cannot install tor because of libevent

Tags: kali-linux, tor

I am trying to install tor on Kali Linux 2019.4 and keep getting the following issue after running `apt-get install tor`.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 tor : Depends: libevent-2.0-5 (>= 2.0.10-stable) but it is not installable
       Recommends: tor-geoipdb but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: torsocks but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have libevent installed as seen here:

```
libevent-2.1-6/now 2.1.8-stable-4 amd64 [installed,local]
  Asynchronous event notification library

libevent-2.1-7/now 2.1.11-stable-1 amd64 [installed,local]
  Asynchronous event notification library

libevent-core-2.1-7/now 2.1.11-stable-1 amd64 [installed,local]
  Asynchronous event notification library (core)
```

I have no idea how to fix this issue, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please repost the above data as text? It's much easier to read.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Thanks for contributing! But please, don't post images of text ([read this for reasons why](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)).

Comment: @ajgringo619  I have done so. Sorry about that.

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` and try again; your repos may be out of sync. When I ran `sudo apt depends tor` I got "Depends: libevent-2.1-7 (>= 2.1.8-stable)".

Comment: @ajgringo619 I still get the same issue.

Comment: Have you added any PPAs for tor? What does `apt policy tor` show?

Comment: @ajgringo619 apt policy tor shows:tor:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.4.1.6-1~d9.stretch+1
  Version table:
     0.4.1.6-1~d9.stretch+1 500
        500 https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org stretch/main amd64 Packages

Comment: @ajgringo619 I added deb https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org stretch main
              deb-src https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org stretch main   to my sources.list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to remove the PPA, as it's conflicting with packages that have already been installed. On my system, `apt policy tor` returns this:

```
tor:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.4.1.6-1+b1
  Version table:
     0.4.1.6-1+b1 500
        500 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages
```

After removing it, run `sudo apt update`, then you should be able to install tor. Unless you have other PPAs installed, your **/etc/apt/sources.list** file should only have this:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
# deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

Comment: after doing that I get the issue:  Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package tor is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'tor' has no installation candidate

Comment: Does `apt policy tor` show what I posted?

Comment: no, it shows: tor:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:

Comment: Check my last edit.

Comment: My sources.list looks like:  deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
# deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
#deb [trusted=yes] http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
#deb [trusted=yes] http://security.kali.org/kali-security/ sana/updates mates main contrib non-free

But I still get the same issue.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what else to try. I'll keep researching.

Comment: It worked. I just restarted my virtual machine and did apt update again, and then apt-get install tor worked.  Thank you so much.